# Data Driven Testing Nightwatch

Tags: nightwatch.js

I am currently working on deciding a tool for automation an app on react/redux platform.
Most of the scenarios that I have in the app is possible to automate using nightwatch.
There are certain test cases or scenarios which repeat itself for different data sets.
For eg. 
Steps to be executed:

1. Login to the application
2. Enter search criteria Step
3. Enter Color 1, Color 2, Color 3
4. Save and Validate

Test Data:

```
|UserName|Password|Search Criteria|Color 1|Color 2|Color 3|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|abc     |  abc   | search 1      |red    |       |       |      
|abc     |  abc   | search 1      |       |green  |       |  
|abc     |  abc   | search 2      |grey   |white  |       |
|abc     |  abc   | search 3      |white  |black  | yellow|
```

I have to execute the same set of code/steps multiple times depending the number of rows of test data we have.
I tried reading a lot of documentations but could not find any package which supports this type of automation in nightwatch.
Please help. Please do let me know if you need any more information.

Thanks & Regards,
Mukesh Panda

Comment: you can use nightwatch-cucumber for data driven testing :

https://github.com/mucsi96/nightwatch-cucumber/

By using **features** and **definitions** from it, you can have your own data as parameters.

or

https://github.com/wsbaser/nightwatch-data-driven

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to place the test data in a JSON file and read it in your testpage file. and call it from testfile. something like,

loginPage.js contains

```
    setCredentials : function (username, password) {
    browser.setValue('#username', username);
     browser.setValue('#password', password);
}
    module.exports=loginPage;
```

and call the function in your test file like
loginTest.js contains

```
     testData = require('testData.json');
     loginPage = require('loginPage.js');
     login = new loginPage(browser);
     login.setCredentials(testData.username, testData.password);
```

something like this you can achieve it...